# nginx - content-disposition file extension

Tags: nginx

I got a working `/api/{UUID}` served by a backend non controlled by me.
I need to add a `/download/{UUID}` the serves the same content, but saving a file with extension .json

i tried:

```
 location ~ "^/download/([a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12})$" {
                rewrite /download/(.*) /api/$1  break;
                set $id $1;
                set $fname '${id}.json';
                add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$fname"';
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        }
```

but the downloaded file is always missing the extension.
what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the order of directives from the [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html). While by most parts nginx config is declarative, directives from the rewrite module are imperative ones and being executed in order of appearance. That `break` flag from the `rewrite` directive makes nginx to stop executing any further directives from the rewrite module, which makes your `set` statements never get executed at all. You can change the order of those directives:

```
location ~ "^/download/([a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12})$" {
    set $id $1;
    set $fname '${id}.json';
    rewrite /download/(.*) /api/$1  break;
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$fname"';
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}
```

However I think it would be simpler to use named captures:

```
location ~ "^/download/(?<id>[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12})$" {
    rewrite ^ /api/$id  break;
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$id.json"';
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}
```

Or even this:

```
location ~ "^/download/(?<id>[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12})$" {
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$id.json"';
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/$id;
}
```

(I used `127.0.0.1` here instead of `localhost` or this configuration would require a `resolver` to resolve the `localhost` hostname to `127.0.0.1` IP address. Yeah, sometimes using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` makes some things different.)